# Python argparse require one or the other arguments

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

I am trying to set the following conditions in argparse:

1. If `--startdate` then require `--enddate`,
2. If `--month` then require `--year`
3. If `--week_num` then require `--year`

Only require one of the above bullet items, i.e, either 1 or 2 or 3, and if more than one is specified then error out. So basically the user can specify the start and end date, or the month and year or the week and year.

For example:

`$ myprog --startdate 01-01-2022 --enddate 01-07-2022`

OR

`$ myprog --month 1 --year 2022`

OR

`$ myprog --week 1 --year 2022`

If a user does something like this, then there should be an error:

`$ myprog --week 1 --enddate 01-07-2022`

I am not sure how to accomplish this using argparse. I looked into mutually exclusive groups, but that seems to not allow for pair.

Comment: argparse doesn't provide that kind of testing